# PRE tag ignoring newlines

Tags: css, salesforce

I have a textarea where the user enters input:

```
 <textarea class="edit_note_text"></textarea>

 

.edit_note_text {
    overflow-y: auto;
    resize: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    margin: 10px 16px 0px;
    width: 1156px;
    height: 70px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    }
```

It is then saved, and sent to our backend in SALESFORCE. The dialog box the textarea is in closes, and the user sees his saved input.

```
<pre>{!creditDeptNote.Description__c}</pre>
```

For some reason, if he enters any linebreaks originally, it saves and displays correctly. But on edit, it removes linebreaks. The backend does seem to be saving the line breaks, and whitespace is showing.

Additionally, there is an extra tab on the line displayed.

Original input:

```
testing                                                                         
t2                                                                              
t3
```

Edit:

```
testing                                                                         
t2                                                                              
t3
567
```

Display:

```
testing                                                                         
t2                                                                              
         t3567
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I couldn't: https://jsfiddle.net/ef9rLzdh/
Everything seem to work just fine. can you please try to make a test case?

Comment: @ItayGanor, thanks for that, I am looking into the backend being the issue.

Comment: I had something similar in one of  my projects, you might want to use `\n\r` for newlines